# Collapsing multiple columns with repeating values

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am currently working with a previously collected dataframe. Participant race is currently split among several categories (Race_White, Race_Black, etc.) where each participant has a value of 1 for Yes or 2 for No. For example, a White participant that does not identify with any other race would have a 1 in the Race_White column and 2's in all other Race_X columns.

I would like to merge these into one "Race" column, where 1 = White, 2 = Black, etc. Does anyone know of a nice piece of code/function/package to do this efficiently?

This is what I have been trying:

```
Race <- mutate(mydata,
                  Race = case_when(
                    mydata$Race_White = 1 & mydata$Race_Black = 2 & mydata$Race_Asian = 2 & mydata$Race_NoReply = 2 ~ 1, 
                    mydata$Race_White = 2 & mydata$Race_Black = 1 & mydata$Race_Asian = 2 & mydata$Race_NoReply = 2 ~ 2, 
                    mydata$Race_White = 2 & mydata$Race_Black = 2 & mydata$Race_Asian = 1 & mydata$Race_NoReply = 2 ~ 3,
                    mydata$Race_White = 2 & mydata$Race_Black = 2 & mydata$Race_Asian = 2 & mydata$Race_NoReply = 1 ~ 4, 
                    TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

Comment: Would be easier if you included `dput(mydata)` in the post.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `pivot_longer` and `str_remove` like this:

```
tib <- tibble::tibble(#example data
  individual = 1:10,
  race_white = sample(c(0,1), 10, T),
  race_black = 1 - race_white
)
tib %>% 
  dplyr::pivot_longer(dplyr::contains('race')) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(value == 1) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    name = stringr::str_remove(name, 'race_')
  ) %>% 
    dplyr::select(-value, race = name)
```

If you want them integer coded you could use `case_when` on the character column.
But it is hard to know exactly what u want without example data.

Here is the output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   individual race 
        <int> <chr>
 1          1 white
 2          2 white
 3          3 white
 4          4 white
 5          5 white
 6          6 white
 7          7 black
 8          8 white
 9          9 white
10         10 black
```

**Edit:**
I used 0 = No, and 1 = Yes. But that does not change anything. I also added package notation to all functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
  names(df)[max.col(df==1)]

 [1] "Race_yellow" "Race_red"    "Race_green"  "Race_red"    "Race_green"  "Race_yellow"
 [7] "Race_red"    "Race_purple" "Race_purple" "Race_yellow" "Race_yellow" "Race_blue"  
[13] "Race_purple" "Race_red"    "Race_purple"
```

The data:

```
df <- read.table(text = 
  "Race_yellow Race_green Race_purple Race_blue Race_red
1            1          2           2         2        2
2            2          2           2         2        1
3            2          1           2         2        2
4            2          2           2         2        1
5            2          1           2         2        2
6            1          2           2         2        2
7            2          2           2         2        1
8            2          2           1         2        2
9            2          2           1         2        2
10           1          2           2         2        2
11           1          2           2         2        2
12           2          2           2         1        2
13           2          2           1         2        2
14           2          2           2         2        1
15           2          2           1         2        2")
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. The table you showed looks more the the "Before" stage. I added some code to clarify what I am looking for. Using this example, I would want Race_Yellow Race_Green etc combined into one Race column, where Race_yellow = 1, race_green = 2, etc, with a total in my sample of 4 Race levels.

Comment: @Paul this is what you are looking for eg. do `as.integer(factor( names(df)[max.col(df==1)]))`